# Why Can a Plane Not Be Defined Solely With a Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, 3d

Why can a vector not be used to define a plane, why does it have to be a vector **and** a point. Couldn't you just take a vector and draw a plane at the tip which is perpendicular to the "stem" of the vector in all directions?

Comment: That's assuming that the vector starts at the point $0$, so even then you are still using a vector and a point. The requirement that a plane be defined with a point and a vector is just more useable, because you often have scenarios where a plane arises from a special point in your space, so having a vector from that point to describe it is just more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plane through the origin can always be described this way, but a description like this cannot distinguish between a plane through the origin and a parallel translate of the same plane.

I like to emphasize that in the setting of multivariable calculus, a vector that is thought of as an arrow doesn't really have a base point; it doesn't 'start somewhere'. It's really *only* a direction and a magnitude